# Server not reachable but only from one PC in subnet

Tags: windows

First of all i'm not an IT-specialist but I was asked to resolve this problem. I will try to explain it as good as I can.

I have got two subnets 172.16.22 and 172.16.222. These subnets are bridged so I can network between those subnets.

Quite recently a server (server B) was added, because this server is owned by a different company it is placed in another subnet 10.13.207. A connection between those subnets is made aswell. From all the other PC's I can reach this server by webbrowser and ping requests.

The problem is I want to reach this server with another server (server B). This server is installed in the 172.16.22 subnet but can't reach the new server. I've tried te following but I can't seem to get it to work.

- Check for a proxy server (nope)
- Compare internet settings to a PC that can connect (settings are the same but still no connection)
- ping from server A to server B (connection timed-out)
- tracert from server A to server B (connection timed-out)
- tracert from PC to server B (one hop on DNS-server)
- Check HOST file (ok).
- Check firewall (was already turned off)

Can someone please help me? Both servers are running Windows but I only have access to server A. I've already contacted the ISP (it's a special one for secured networks for healthcare) but they say everything is set-up ok.

Best regards,
Tim

Comment: Look at routing tables on a PC on the 172.16.22.x subnet that CAN reach the 10.13.207.x server.  Then compare these to routing tables on your server that cannot reach the 10.13.207.x server. (open command prompt, enter command 'route print')

Comment: I've compared both routes but I can't find any substantial difference. I can see that the server has two more routes. I don't see the 10.13.207.x server in both routes.

Comment: There should either be an explicit entry for a specific gateway for the 10.13.207.x subnet, or there should be no entry, and the default gateway would be used.  If those settings are the same on both the server and the PC, then it means network traffic is taking the same "path", but the server's traffic is being blocked for some reason.  I would then check into the security policies in place on whatever device/server is bridging the subnets.

Comment: I've tried to add a route (no guts no glory, right?) and it is working :). Thanks for all the help!